# Apply function to every current and future element matching the selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this:

```
 $("form").prepend('<div class="errors"></div>');
```

to every form that is currently on the page and any form that will be loaded in later (using ajax) or added by js.

Something similar to:

```
 $("form").live("submit",function(){
     $("form").prepend('<div class="errors"></div>');
 })
```

Without having to manually (re)apply the wanted actions on loading some ajax.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a good, cross-browser solution for this. There are the [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) such as [`DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljimhdto.php) and [`DOMSubtreeModified`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified), however they're not supported in IE or Firefox, and in any case, they are deprecated, so it's not a great idea to rely upon them.

I would suggest revisiting the 'manual' approach. You should probably know when you are modifying the document, (eg: retrieving some HTML via AJAX and inserting it), so you can perform whatever action you need at that point in time.

Comment: This was just for the example, i'll update it to make it more "real life scenario"

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but I guess i'll have to live with it :)